# Allow location path with querystring in web.config

Tags: asp.net, path, web-config

I have this in my web.config

```
  <location path="ChangePassword.aspx">
     <system.web>
       <authorization>
         <allow users="*"/>
       </authorization>
     </system.web>   </location>
```

The problem is that, while accessing the page works, i need to allow acces to this page with querystrings as well, which does not work:

- ChangePassword.aspx?mode=
- ChangePassword.aspx?userid=xx&mode=

How can I do that? The parameters will have dynamic values all the time of course, I cant hardcode IDs in web.config.

EDIT for better understanding of the problem

The purpose= non-logged user must have access to the ChangePassword.aspx page with any querystrings it receives.

The problem for non-logged users:

- They can access `ChangePassword.aspx`
- They can NOT access `ChangePassword.aspx?parameter=value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a user can access the page, they can add a query string to the path.

The authorization mechanism operates on the file location only - you can't make it operate on the query string parameters.

If you want to change the page behaviour according to the parameters you should do that in your page code.

You can easily access the query string parameters on the page:

```
Request.QueryString["UserId"]
```

Comment: i don't understand the explanation - what do you mean by "page behaviour" ? i want to operate on the user on this page, which is why i pass the userid in querystring.

Comment: @AndreiCristof - "i want to operate on the user on this page". Was I supposed to guess that? Read your question please. What exactly "does not work"? You can pass in the parameters on the querystring - if the user can access the page, the parameters will go with it. They will not get stripped out. What are you actually having difficulties with?

Comment: I have carefully reread the question and i think i formulated it clearly. If I access ChangePassword.aspx as a nonlogged user it works. If I access ChangePassword.aspx?parameter=value as a nonlogged user it doesnt.

Comment: @AndreiCristof - You say "i need to allow acces to this page with querystrings as well". If you gave access to the user, they can access it with or without query strings. If they can't access _with_ query strings, something else is going on.

Comment: i have edited the question to be more precise. I have retested and the user who is not logged can NOT access the page if it has a querystring. if the page has no querystring, the user CAN access. that is my dillema

Comment: i saw your edited answer and i probably need to explain more - i do know how to access the querystring inside the page, thats no issue, the problem is that the user does not REACH the page, if it was called with a querystring.

Comment: I found the issue. You were correct, there was something else going on, the parameter itself was not the issue. A HttpModule was redirecting on every request, if the parameter it received was not among the ones he "liked". I apologize for wasting your time.

Comment: @AndreiCristof - Not wasting time at all... The problem you had and the reason you though you had it were not right, and you made the question very much to your assumption of the problem...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the web.config: your settings regarding the  tag are correct. 
The problem is the link

```
ChangePassword.aspx?Userid=xx&mode=
```

The character that does not allow a correct routing to your page is the "**&**".

Make sure it is written using proper Xml encoding (which, amont other things, will replace all '&' characters with '&').

This should work well:

```
ChangePassword.aspx?Userid=xx&amp;mode=
```

Or you can use

> System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(yourUrl);

I hope it is useful ;)